# Aplicando gravedad a partículas, en Processing, ¿Cómo crear una partícula al hacer click?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing

tengo que crear un programa para entregar en la universidad en el que se refleje todo lo aprendido en la carrera (Ingeniería electrónica).Mi idea, es hacer un programa simple, en el que cada vez que des click al ratón aparezca una fórmula matemática aleatoria en la posición del ratón y caiga por gravedad. Antes de meterme en como meter fórmulas en processing (Como por ejemplo, con formato LaTeX), quiero hacerlo simple, con una simple particula.

El problema que tengo en el código adjunto, es que cuando doy click inicializo la posición del vector, pero salta error evidentemente en el draw() cuando llamo al método ps.run() indicando un NullPointerException , ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Si es demasiado complicado hacerlo (tengo nivel básico de Processing), ¿A alguien se le ocurre una idea mejor para hacer otro programa distinto?

Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.

```java
Particle ps;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ps.run();
}

// A simple Particle class.

void mouseClicked() {

  ps  = new Particle(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}

class Particle {
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float lifespan;

  Particle(PVector l) {
    acceleration = new PVector(0, 0.05);
    velocity = new PVector(random(-1, 1), random(-2, 0));
    position = l.copy();
    lifespan = 255.0;
  }

  void run() {
    update();
    display();
  }

  // Method to update position
  void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    position.add(velocity);
    lifespan -= 1.0;
  }

  // Method to display
  void display() {
    stroke(255, lifespan);
    fill(255, lifespan);
    ellipse(position.x, position.y, 8, 8);
  }

  // Is the particle still useful?
  boolean isDead() {
    if (lifespan < 0.0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema con tu código es que llamabas a un método de un objeto que aún no inicializabas. Y aunque lo hubieras inicializado. Solo hubieras podido ver una partícula a la vez. Por lo que consideré  mejor guardar cada partícula en un ArrayList Y luego llamar por cada objeto en la lista al método run(). Así también al hacer click se agregaba una partícula al ArrayList. Le agregué una forma de eliminar rápidamente las partículas que salían de la pantalla utilizando tu método isDead().

```
ArrayList<Particle> ps;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  ps = new ArrayList<Particle>();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for ( int i = 0; i < ps.size(); i++ ) {
    ps.get(i).run();
    if ( ps.get(i).isDead() ) {
      ps.remove(i);
    }
  }
}

// A simple Particle class.

void mouseClicked() {
  
  ps.add( new Particle(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY)) );
}

class Particle {
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float lifespan;

  Particle(PVector l) {
    acceleration = new PVector(0, 0.05);
    velocity = new PVector(random(-1, 1), random(-2, 0));
    position = l.copy();
    lifespan = 255.0;
  }

  void run() {
    update();
    display();
  }

  // Method to update position
  void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    position.add(velocity);
    lifespan -= 1.0;
  }

  // Method to display
  void display() {
    stroke(255, lifespan);
    fill(255, lifespan);
    ellipse(position.x, position.y, 8, 8);
  }

  // Is the particle still useful?
  boolean isDead() {
    if (lifespan < 0.0 || position.y > height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```